# how to commit and push in libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I just downloaded the nugget package for libgit2sharp. 
I am finding it difficult to do even basic operations.

I have an existing git repo (both remote and local). I just need to commit new changes when it occurs and push it to the remote.

I have the code below to explain what I did.

```cs
string path = @"working direcory path(local)";
Repository repo = new Repository(path);
repo.Commit("commit done for ...");

Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];          
var credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials {Username = "*******", Password = "******"};
var options = new PushOptions();
options.Credentials = credentials;
var pushRefSpec = @"refs/heads/master";                      
repo.Network.Push(remote, pushRefSpec, options, null, "push done...");
```

Where should I specify remote url's ? also is this the right way of doing these operations(commit & push)?

Thanks

Comment: You specify the url as an attribute of the remote. There is no committing going on here, what have you tried for that? What isn't working?

Comment: Well, the remote.url has only getter & no setter !?! Also I am just trying to commit the changes i made in my local working directory & later on push it to the remote repository..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```cs
public void StageChanges() {
    try {
        RepositoryStatus status = repo.Index.RetrieveStatus();
        List<string> filePaths = status.Modified.Select(mods => mods.FilePath).ToList();
        repo.Index.Stage(filePaths);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception:RepoActions:StageChanges " + ex.Message);
    }
}

public void CommitChanges() {
    try {

        repo.Commit("updating files..", new Signature(username, email, DateTimeOffset.Now),
            new Signature(username, email, DateTimeOffset.Now));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception:RepoActions:CommitChanges " + e.Message);
    }
}

public void PushChanges() {
    try {
        var remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
        var options = new PushOptions();
        var credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials { Username = username, Password = password };
        options.Credentials = credentials;
        var pushRefSpec = @"refs/heads/master";
        repo.Network.Push(remote, pushRefSpec, options, new Signature(username, email, DateTimeOffset.Now),
            "pushed changes");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception:RepoActions:PushChanges " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yours was helpful, and thanks for that(+1). But I guess the main focus was on basic operations like commit & push. I just don't want to mislead others.

Comment: Breaking change in LibGit2Sharp Version `0.26.2`: ```var status = repo.RetrieveStatus();
            var filePaths = status.Modified.Select(mods => mods.FilePath).ToList();
            foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
            {
                repo.Index.Add(filePath);
                repo.Index.Write();
            }```

Answer (score 4):

The remote already has an url.

If you wanted to change the url associated with remote named '`origin`', you would need to:

- remove that remote:

  ```cs
  repo.Network.Remotes.Remove("origin");

  # you can check it with:
  Assert.Null(repo.Network.Remotes["origin"]);
  Assert.Empty(repo.Refs.FromGlob("refs/remotes/origin/*"));
  ```
- create a new one (default refspec)

  ```cs
  const string name = "origin";
  const string url = "https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp.git";
  repo.Network.Remotes.Add(name, url);

  # check it with:
  Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes[name];
  Assert.NotNull(remote);
  ```

See more at [`LibGit2Sharp.Tests/RemoteFixture.cs`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/RemoteFixture.cs)

---

As updated [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084890/how-to-commit-and-push-in-libgit2sharp/25091769?noredirect=1#comment40002071_25091769) by [nulltoken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335418/nulltoken), [contributor to libgit2](https://github.com/nulltoken):

> [PR 803](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/803) has been merged.
>   This should allow some code such as

```cs
Remote updatedremote = 
   repo.Network.Remotes.Update(remote, r => r.Url = "http://yoururl");
```

Comment: **[PR #803](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/803)** has been merged. This should allow some code such as `Remote updatedremote = repo.Network.Remotes.Update(remote, r => r.Url = "http://yoururl");`

Comment: @nulltoken that looks nicer indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility;